# Prove that N is a perfect square

Tags: linear-algebra, factoring, pythagorean-triples

The integer $N$ is positive. There are exactly $2005$ ordered pairs $(x, y)$ of positive integers satisfying:

$\frac{1}{x}$ + $\frac{1}{y}$ = $\frac{1}{N}$

Prove that $N$ is a perfect square.

Please explain as if I don't know anything about the topic or please tell me the math topics i need to know to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Try rearranging your equation to $xy-Nx-Ny=0$. Maybe there's a nice factoring trick (perhaps even someone's favorite) that can help from here?

Comment: A Google search has unearthed this: https://socratic.org/questions/given-the-integer-n-0-there-are-exactly-2005-ordered-pairs-x-y-of-positive-integ , which is pretty much the same problem. (They talk about $2017$ rather than $2005$, and the latter requires one additional step.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the equation by expressing $x$ in terms of $y$ and $N$,
$$
x=N+\frac{N^2}{y-N}
$$
Since $x$ and $ N$ are integers, therefore $y-N|N^2$. There are $2005$ such ordered pairs $(x,y)$ implies that $N^2$ has $2005$ divisors. Let the prime factorisation of $N$ be
$$
N=p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_n^{\alpha_n},
\textrm{  then }N^2=p_1^{2\alpha_1} p_2^{2\alpha_2} \cdots p_n^{2\alpha_n},
$$
and the number of divisor of $N^2$ is $2005=\left(2 \alpha_1+1\right)\left(2 \alpha_2+1\right) \cdots\left(2 \alpha_n+1\right) =5 \times 401.$ Consequently, $$
\begin{aligned}
& 2 \alpha_1+1=5 \text { and } 2 \alpha_2+1=401 \\
\Rightarrow \quad & \alpha_1=2 \text { and } \alpha_2=200
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $
N=p_1^2 p_2^{200}=\left(p_1 p_2^{100}\right)^2
$ is a perfect square.

**In general**, if $N^2$ has odd numbers of divisors, then $N$ must be a perfect square.

Comment: Ok i understand better but what does a represent, a power? and how did you get (2α1+1) is that a known formula

Comment: The first is the unique prime factorisation of $N$, where $\alpha$ ‘s are the powers of prime factors.  For example, the integer $12=2^2\times 3^1$ has (2+1)(1+1)=6 divisors.

Comment: is that a theorem  (adding one to the powers of primes and multiplying them)

Comment: i understand the divisor function now but why is it (2a + 1) instead of (a+1)

Comment: $
N^2=p_1^{2\alpha_1} p_2^{2\alpha_2} \cdots p_n^{2\alpha_n},
$

Comment: thank you and can you explain why the formula adds 1 (the total number of divisors theorem)

Comment: It is because you have n+1 choices the take the prime factor $p_i$. Never forget that you can take a divisor without factor $p_i$, in which $p_i^0$. Get it?